# jquery append and remove :removing order is not correct

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to implement a functionality that user can add and remove two text fields (ie heading, and description) using jquery, `add more` functionality is works fine but the `removing` order is not correct.

Hers is the  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsm755vv/) that shows the problem

**Jquery**

```
var append = '<div><div class="form-group"> <label>Day 1</label><input type="text" value="" name="subHeading" class="form-control"></div>';
append += '<div class="form-group"> <label>Description</label> <textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea>';
append += '</div><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove" id="btnAddMore">Remove</button></div>';

$('#btnAddMore').click(function() {
  $('#appendContent:last').before(append);
});

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  //alert('ok');
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Also i need one more thing when a user is click `add more` button I am showing a label thay shows `day 1` if adding another item the it will show `day 2` and so on.

Comment: your jsfiddle looks work, where is the problem ?

Comment: Instead of working around the "links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code" message by randomly marking up non-code as code, **put the code in the question**. (Hint: Stack Snippets [the `<>` toolbar button] can be used to create a runnable demo right here on-site.)

Comment: Add more than 3 items and try a delete it will delete the first item

Comment: it delete everytime the one i want, i don't understand your problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Update `text` of the label after `append/remove`
- Give some `class` to identify parent element of container.

```js
$('.days').text(function(index) {
  return 'Day ' + (index + 1)
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/wsm755vv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
$('#btnAddMore').click(function() {
  var clone = $(append).clone()
  $('#appendContent').append(clone);
  clone.find(".form-group > label").text("Day " + $("#appendContent").children().length);
});
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  //alert('ok');
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wsm755vv/2/)

- Make a copy of the newly created div using clone().
- Then change the label inside the clone() using `.find(".form-group > label").text()`
- Get the number of the current div by counting the children of `"appendContentDiv"`

Comment: You aren't handling the fact you can get duplicate days once one has been removed

Comment: @A.Wolff , yes you are correct.. But I am not sure how OP needs to handle it.

Comment: Its works fine but if i delete an item randomly `days` count order is not proper

Comment: Nop again the orders are mismatched

Answer (score 0):

give class to main div

```
var append='<div class="minus"><div class="form-group">
```

in jquery

```
$(this).closest('.minus').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look attached snippet :

```js
       /* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
var append='<div><div class="form-group"> <label></label><input type="text" value="" name="subHeading" class="form-control"></div>';
       append+='<div class="form-group"> <label>Description</label> <textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea>';
       append+='</div><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove" id="btnAddMore">Remove</button></div>';
       $('#btnAddMore').click(function(){
           $('#appendContent:last').before(append);
                var i=1;
                        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
                            $(this).prev().html('Day '+i);
                            $(this).attr('name', 'subHeading' + i); 
                                $(this).attr('id', 'subHeading' + i); 
                                    i++;
                        });
       });
       $('body').on('click','.remove',function(){
           //alert('ok');
           $(this).parent().remove();
           var i=1;
                        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
              $(this).prev().html('Day '+i);
                            $(this).attr('name', 'subHeading' + i); 
                                $(this).attr('id', 'subHeading' + i); 
                                    i++;
                        });
       });
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"id="btnAddMore">Addmore</button>
    <!--for append -->
    <div id="appendContent">
    </div>
    
    <!--end append-->
                  
</div>
```

As well as please have a look attached fiddle.

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dinvi/pzzg2v55/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var appendContentSize = $('#appendContent .appended-element').size();
       $('#btnAddMore').click(function(){
            var append='<div class="appended-element"><div class="form-group"> <label>Day '+appendContentSize+'</label><input type="text" value="" name="subHeading" class="form-control"></div>';

       append+='<div class="form-group"> <label>Description</label> <textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea>';
       append+='</div><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove" id="btnAddMore">Remove</button></div>';
           $('#appendContent').append(append);
           appendContentSize++
       });
       $('body').on('click','.remove',function(){
           //alert('ok');
           if(appendContentSize > 0){
                $(this).parent().remove();
            appendContentSize--
           }
       });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/giantomakin/wsm755vv/8/